# Is it always necessary to connect SATA (or MOLEX) power to PCIe-USB-3.0 adapter cards?

Tags: power, usb-3

I would like to put a PCIe-USB-3.0 adapter card into one of my PCs. I have noticed that nearly all of such adapter cards have a power connector (either MOLEX or SATA).

I would like to know if I can use such adapter cards without the extra power connected provided that I connect only USB devices which don't consume much power. In other words, do I need to connect the extra power only for USB devices which violate the USB specifications in that the current they draw is too high, for example external 3.5" hard drives?

Actually, I am interested in the following adapter card:
https://www.amazon.de/CSL-Express-Controller-SATA-Stromanschluss-Schnittstellenkarte/dp/B00OBB2X9A

Comment: Yes you do, they will not supply power to usb unless you do.

Comment: OK, thank you very much. This will keep me from buying one of these adapters. I'll look for one of the rare alternatives which does not have such a power connector, i.e. which takes the power it needs from the PCIe.

Comment: I think they all need that power connector, never seen one without on pci-e.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid the molex connector due to the fact you don’t have an unused one or just personal preference?

Comment: @Moab Thanks for caring. I have found this in another thread: https://www.amazon.com/Inateck-Expansion-Controller-Additional-Connection/dp/B00JFR2I2C/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1480411237&sr=8-5&keywords=inateck+pci-e

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for bothering. I don't want that connector because it really would mess up the cabling in my case - I would have to use an extra cable for that connector. This is not an option ...

Comment: @Binarus - Just cable manage it.  Your not going to be able to avoid this if you want USB through PCIe

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks again. But the following one seems to do what I want (I don't know what I should think about the chipset, though): https://www.inateck.com/inateck-kt4006-dual-port-usb-3-0-pci-express-card-20-pin-connector-no-power-connection.html

Comment: NEC is a good chipset

Comment: Yes, I know the NEC chips, because they were used on mainboards around 2010, when the Intel northbridge and southbridge didn't incorporate USB 3 yet. However, I didn't find a card with a NEC chip and without additional power yet. The Inateck seems to be the only adapter card without additional power, but its chipset seems to be a little exotic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of add-on PCIe USB cards do work without the auxiliary power supply. In my 10-years experience with USB 3 I have seen only ONE design that won't work without Molex power, and it had a specific warning on PCB, "connect 4-pin power" or something. It was long time ago.

Today it seems that board designers found a way to use both board power and aux power combined. I have six or seven DIFFERENT cards, they all work without aux power with low-power devices. Most recent PCIe add-on boards use 12V to 5V on-board switching regulators, which reduce the ampacity it needs from 12-V rail from mainboard across the PCIe connector. So this solution can provide decent 5V power without overstressing 12V pins. Here are examples:

[image][image]

But usually you rarely know the schematic details. Board of your selection has suspiciously small switching supply, and might rely directly on +5V rail from main PSU and might not work without the aux power.

Comment: Thank you very much - upvoted and accepted. In the meantime, I have bought a card which looks more solid, and I additionally have connected the power to it (just to be prepared for "high-power" devices). To let that thing not become too messy, I have sacrificed one of the modular SATA cables of my power supply (the first connector was far enough from the supply so I could cut the cable directly behind it). I hope that I won't need that cable in the future, because it is not available any more (thank you, Enermax).